# The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rest-client, resthighlevelclient

My API version is 6.3 and I try to create index. The failure says "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true" .Here is my code:

```
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest("user");

request.source("{\n" +
        "    \"settings\" : {\n" +
        "        \"number_of_shards\" : 1,\n" +
        "        \"number_of_replicas\" : 0\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"mappings\" : {\n" +
        "        \"_doc\" : {\n" +
        "            \"properties\" : {\n" +
        "                \"message\" : { \"type\" : \"text\" }\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"aliases\" : {\n" +
        "        \"twitter_alias\" : {}\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}", XContentType.JSON);
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = restHighLevelClient.indices().create(indexRequest);
```

After I remove "_doc" as following, failure says  "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [properties]". So what should I do now?

```
 request.source("{\n" +
            "    \"settings\" : {\n" +
            "        \"number_of_shards\" : 1,\n" +
            "        \"number_of_replicas\" : 0\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"mappings\" : {\n" +
            "       
            "            \"properties\" : {\n" +
            "                \"message\" : { \"type\" : \"text\" }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "     
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"aliases\" : {\n" +
            "        \"twitter_alias\" : {}\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}", XContentType.JSON);
```

Comment: What is your Elasticsearch version? And what API are you talking about? C#?

Comment: Its really long, would be great if you can upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 13):

`_doc` was a temporary type name which was kept for backward compatibility and to prepare for removing it, refer [removal of type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) for more details on this.

Also refer [schedule and how to handle this breaking change on your version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types)

1. Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name
   can be used for the type, but there can be only one. The preferred
   type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they
   will have in 7.0: PUT {index}/_doc/{id} and POST {index}/_doc

Also please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html#_migrating_multi_type_indices_to_single_type this section where its explained how to use it in 6.X.

I would suggest first try to create a index using REST API and see with the combination of `include_type_name` and `index.mapping.single_type` it works or not and accordingly add it in your code.

Answer (score 9):

The reason was a mapping API query. I fixed as below.

```
# ES6
PUT myindex
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {                 <--------- Delete this layer
            "properties": {
                "blahblah": {
 
# ES7
PUT myindex
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "blahblah": {
```